# Thinkphp add php extension

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

Now my nginx rewrite conf:

```
location{
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite  ^(.*)$  /index.php?s=$1  last;
        break;
    }
}
```

The right url is :

```
http://aaa.com/api/home?id=1
```

Now i want to add the php extention,the url change to :

```
http://aaa.com/api/home.php?id=1
```

How should i configure my nginx?